# Using classes in a python program and incrementing points

Tags: python, class, module

I need to create a final project for a Beginning Python class and I decided to create a riddle program and want to simplify the following code, but am unsure how to do it. I would like to use a class to do this, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change my main program to use the information from Class The program runs fine without using Class, but I have to use it for the final project. I am unsure how to do this, I've tried a few things like doing a points system (5 points increment for each win) and thought it would be nice to make the riddles/answers etc. into a class. The problem I'm having is how to code the self instances in the program itself. I know to import the class, but I'm struggling with how/what to change in the program without screwing everything up.. I've looked all over Stack Overflow and a variety of other internet resources, and believe I have a decent understanding of classes, importing and inheritance, but I can't seem to find any examples similar to what I'm trying to do.. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import riddle_class

banner = "~Riddle Me This~"

print(banner)
print('')
print('Instructions: You have 10 chances to answer each of the following 5 riddles.\
You will receive 5 points for each riddle you answer – up to 25 points.')

points = {'win': 0}

riddle_one = 'What\'s round, but not always around. It is light sometimes and is dark sometimes. Everyone wants to walk all over me. What am I?'
riddle_two = 'What has roots as nobody sees, Is taller than trees, Up, up it goes, And yet never grows?'
riddle_three = 'Voiceless it cries, Wingless flutters, Toothless bites, Mouthless mutters. What am I?'
riddle_four = 'Tear one off and scratch my head; what was once red is black instead.'
riddle_five = 'We\'re five little items of an everyday sort; you\'ll find us all in a tennis court'

riddle_one_answer = 'moon'
riddle_two_answer = 'mountain'
riddle_three_answer = 'wind'
riddle_four_answer = 'match'
riddle_five_answer = 'vowels'

hidden_one = '-' * len(riddle_one_answer)
hidden_two = '-' * len(riddle_two_answer)
hidden_three = '-' * len(riddle_three_answer)
hidden_four = '-' * len(riddle_four_answer)
hidden_five = '-' * len(riddle_five_answer)

guess_one = 0
guess_two = 0
guess_three = 0
guess_four = 0
guess_five = 0

points = 0

score = {'win':0}

print('')

#Riddle One
print('~Riddle Number One!~')
print(riddle_one)
print('')

while guess_one < 11:
    print(hidden_one)
    user_input = input('Enter one letter at a time (guess #%d): ' % guess_one)
    if len(user_input) != 1:
        continue

    # Count the number of times the character occurs in the word
    num_occurrences = riddle_one_answer.count(user_input)

    # Replace the appropriate position(s) in hidden_word with the actual character.
    position = -1
    for occurrence in range(num_occurrences):
        position = riddle_one_answer.find(user_input, position+1)  # Find the position of the next occurrence
        hidden_one = hidden_one[:position] + user_input + hidden_one[position+1:]  # Rebuild the hidden word string

    if not '-' in hidden_one:
        print('')
        print('Nice Job!', end=' ')
        results = 'win'
        break

    guess_one += 1
else:
    print('Loser!', end=' ')
    print('The word was %s' % riddle_one_answer,'\.')

print('______________________________________')
print('')

#Riddle Two
print('')
print('~Riddle Number Two!~')
print(riddle_two)
print('')

while guess_two < 11:
    print(hidden_two)
    user_input = input('Enter one letter at a time (guess #%d): ' % guess_two)
    if len(user_input) != 1:
        continue

    # Count the number of times the character occurs in the word
    num_occurrences = riddle_two_answer.count(user_input)

    # Replace the hidden_word with the character.
    position = -1
    for occurrence in range(num_occurrences):
        position = riddle_two_answer.find(user_input, position+1)  # Find the position of the next occurrence
        hidden_two = hidden_two[:position] + user_input + hidden_two[position+1:]  # Rebuild the hidden word string

    if not '-' in hidden_two:
        print('')
        print('WINNER!', end=' ')
        results = 'win'
        break

    guess_two += 1
else:
    print('Loser!', end=' ')
    print('The word was: %s' % riddle_two_answer,'\.')
print('______________________________________')
print('')

#Riddle Three
print('')
print('~Riddle Number Three!~')
print(riddle_three)
print('')

while guess_three < 11:
    print(hidden_three)
    user_input = input('Enter one letter at a time (guess #%d): ' % guess_three)
    if len(user_input) != 1:
        continue

    # Count the number of times the character occurs in the word
    num_occurrences = riddle_three_answer.count(user_input)

    # Replace the appropriate position(s) in hidden_word with the actual character.
    position = -1
    for occurrence in range(num_occurrences):
        position = riddle_three_answer.find(user_input, position+1)  # Find the position of the next occurrence
        hidden_three = hidden_three[:position] + user_input + hidden_three[position+1:]  # Rebuild the hidden word string

    if not '-' in hidden_three:
        print('')
        print('WINNER!', end=' ')
        results = 'win'
        break

    guess_three += 1
else:
    print('Loser!', end=' ')
    print('The word was %s' % riddle_three_answer,'/.')
print('______________________________________')
print('')

#Riddle Four
print('')
print('~Riddle Number Four!~')
print(riddle_four)
print('')
while guess_four < 11:
    print(hidden_four)
    user_input = input('Enter one letter at a time (guess #%d): ' % guess_four)
    if len(user_input) != 1:
        continue

    # Count the number of times the character occurs in the word
    num_occurrences = riddle_four_answer.count(user_input)

    # Replace the appropriate position(s) in hidden_word with the actual character.
    position = -1
    for occurrence in range(num_occurrences):
        position = riddle_four_answer.find(user_input, position+1)  # Find the position of the next occurrence
        hidden_four = hidden_four[:position] + user_input + hidden_four[position+1:]  # Rebuild the hidden word string

    if not '-' in hidden_four:
        print('')
        print('WINNER!', end=' ')
        results = 'win'
        break

    guess_four += 1
else:
    print('Loser!', end=' ')
    print('The word was %s' % riddle_four_answer,'/.')
print('______________________________________')
print('')

#Riddle Five
print('')
print('~Riddle Number Five!~')
print(riddle_five)
print('')

while guess_five < 11:
    print(hidden_five)
    user_input = input('Enter one letter at a time (guess #%d): ' % guess_five)
    if len(user_input) != 1:
        continue

    # Count the number of times the character occurs in the word
    num_occurrences = riddle_five_answer.count(user_input)

    # Replace the appropriate position(s) in hidden_word with the actual character.
    position = -1
    for occurrence in range(num_occurrences):
        position = riddle_five_answer.find(user_input, position+1)  # Find the position of the next occurrence
        hidden_five = hidden_five[:position] + user_input + hidden_five[position+1:]  # Rebuild the hidden word string

    if not '-' in hidden_five:
        print('')
        print('WINNER!', end=' ')
        results = 'win'
        break

    guess_five += 1
else:
    print('Loser!', end=' ')
    print('The word was %s' % riddle_five_answer,'/.')
print('______________________________________')
print('')

if results == 'win':
    score['win'] += 1
    total_wins = (score['win'])
    points += 5 * total_wins

print('Total points: %d' % points) *#This is only recognizing 1 'win'*
```

**Class**

```
class riddle_me:

    def __init__(self, turns, guess):
        self.turns = 5
        guess = 0

score = {'wins': 0}

    def __init__(self):
        guess_one = 0
        guess_two = 0
        guess_three = 0
        guess_four = 0
        guess_five = 0
```

UPDATE
Thank you all for your help and questions. Even the questions got me thinking more about my project. I still haven't completed the program yet, but I know it could work. I just need to practice more. I've been studying  nonstop, but for some reason I'm struggling to learn this language no matter how many tutorials I search.

Comment: what is with the two init methods and what part are you stuck with?

Comment: The init methods were just to show examples of things I was trying to create to make the class work. I know it doesn't look right, but i'm just stuck on the whole creation and implementation itself. I have looked at different codes to implement a 'win' counter and want to calculate the total wins at the end of the program, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly when I run it in the program itself.

Comment: -I'm not even sure if I'm asking the question correctly. I want to be able to take that code and import a class to add the number of points the user got at the end. It seems like that should be relatively simple, I've done score increments in other programs, but I don't know how to get them into a class and then run it in the main program...

Comment: Do you mean a running total for many games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you understand what a class is, right? So your question really is, "how should I use classes in this program?"

Usually the best way to figure out what classes (and objects) you need in a program is to sit down and write out a description of what your program is trying to do, and then pick out words from that. For example:

> This riddle **game** will ask the **user** a series of **questions**, and each time compare the **user**'s **guess** with the correct **answer**. When the **user** **guesses** correctly, the **user**'s **points** will increase. If the **user** does not **guess** correctly after 10 **guesses**, we will move to the next **question**. After all the **questions** have been asked, the **game** will display the **user**'s **points**.

OK, so this is still pretty straightforward. I've highlighted some of the words that occur more than once. Each of these words represents an idea that might be usefully made into a class: the **game** itself, each **question**, the user's **guess**.

Some of these things don't need to be their own objects, but can be properties of other objects. For example, notice how we kept referring to "the user's points". Clearly the **points** number is an attribute of the **user** object. And the correct **answer** to a question should be an attribute of that **question**.

OK, so now we have some "things" we're going to use in our program, and some idea of what we want to know about each of them:

```
User:
   has points (a number)

Question:
   has question text (a string)
   has correct answer (a string)

Guess:
   has the text of the guess, what the user entered (a string)
   is either right or wrong (a boolean)

Game:
   has 5 questions
```

OK, these are starting to look like classes! We can translate these into classes pretty directly:

```
class User:
   def __init__(self):
       self.points = 0  # user starts out with zero points

class Question:
     def __init__(self, question_text, correct_answer):
         self.question_text = question_text
         self.correct_answer = correct_answer            

class Guess:
     def __init__(self, text, is_correct):
         self.text = text
         self.is_correct = is_correct

class Game:
    def __init__(self, questions):
        self.questions = questions
```

Now we have some objects, but we can't do anything useful with them. Now we need to decide what **methods** to add. There's more than one right way to do this (and a lot of subtle tradeoffs, depending on which things you care more or less about).

Let's start, though, by identifying **things we want to be able to do**:

- ask a `Question`, that is, print out its `question_text`
- read in a `Guess` from the user
- determine whether a `Guess` matches a `Question`'s `correct_answer` text
- add `points` to a `User`
- find the next `Question` in a `Game`, or determine when there are no more questions

Each of these **things we want to do** should be a method! Now you're breaking down your program into smaller and smaller pieces. Keep doing it until it becomes obvious what each piece should do -- and then translate each piece into code. That's it!

Some of these things could potentially live in multiple places. Some things to think about:

- Should reading in a `Guess` from the user be a method on `Guess` or on `User`? Either one is OK. Or it could even be a separate function (not a method of a class).
- Where should the function that determines whether a `Guess` is correct or not live? Right now I have it as an attribute of the `Guess` class, but maybe it should be a method on `Guess` like `is_correct_answer_to(question)` that takes the question and returns `True` or `False`.
- Where should we keep track of the number of guesses so far for a particular question? It could either be on the `Question` object, or on the `User` object. Or it could just be a local variable in a function like `ask_question(question)` which could live either on `Question` or maybe on `Game`, or maybe not as a member of a class.

These are the decisions you need to make. But hopefully this will help you get started!

Comment: @ Daniel Pryden: THANK YOU so much for your guidance on the creating of classes! I have tried using flow charts and other ideas but writing things out in terms of what I want to do and highlighting specific pieces was of tremendous help. I do understand how to make classes, but yes, creating classes for THIS program is troublesome for me. I am struggling with how to actually use them in the program itself. Where I would put them in the code. I tried riddle_one = riddle_class.Riddle() and then riddle_one = (the riddle text) print (riddle_one)  but I know that's not the right way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible places to put a class into your code. One is urgently needed, the other not so much (but it could come in handy if you want to add new features to the program).

The obvious place to use a class is to encapsulate all the data and logic related to a single riddle. Each instance of the class would have attributes for the question, the answer, and perhaps other things that would be modified as the player tries to solve the riddle (the masked solution shown to the player and a list of the guesses so far, perhaps).

Something like this:

```
class Riddle(object):
    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.guesses = []
        self.update_mask()

    def update_mask(self):
        self.masked_answer = "".join(c if c in self.guesses else "-"
                                       for c in self.answer)

    def guess(self, letter):
        # perhaps do some sanity checking here, for invalid or duplicated letters
        self.guesses.append(letter)
        self.update_mask()

        # return number of letters just matched, number yet to be guessed
        return self.answer.count(letter), self.masked_answer.count("-")
```

The other place you might use a class is to encapsulate the game logic (e.g. how many guesses the user gets to make, how they score points) and state (e.g. the player's score and the list of `Riddle`s to ask). This would let you adapt your program in various ways, like letting the player play again after they complete the first run.

However, I don't think that using a class for this is nearly as important as it was for the riddles. Most of the benefits would simply come from gathering the game logic into functions, rather than repeating it over and over. Make an `ask_riddle` function to handle a single riddle and return the score the player earned and your code will get a whole lot cleaner. If you want to make it a method of the `Game` class, and update the instance with the score instead, that works too. Python doesn't require you to write object oriented code (though it does make it easy to do so), so you don't need to wedge classes in where they're not needed.

Comment: :Thank you so much for these ideas, they really helped a lot with getting started. I had tried doing a class for each riddle, answer, hidden character and guess, but it seemed almost more convoluted than the program running as is. While I understand how to make classes, actually using them in the program is something I'm struggling with. For example, making riddle_one  use the features of the Riddle class. I tried riddle_one = riddle_class.Riddle() and then riddle_one = (the riddle text) print (riddle_one)  but I know that's not the right way to do that.